# How big size of File stream folders created automatically in RBS folder for a content database

Tags: 2010, sql-server-2012, rbs

There is a content database configured with RBS , and this RBS folder size is 2 TB, and web application has used to upload documents mostly and  working fine but in the last weekend there is no activity by users and there is no users upload documents to web application , but we found that some filestream folder created at RBS folder about 1 TB.

Comment: So this folder got created during the last week, while no real activity was reported on webserver level? Did you check IIS logs for corresponding web application?

Comment: yes i checked in iis logs there is activity recorded on those days, do i have any another way to check from sharepoint side?

Comment: Was that *there is **no** activity*? It's not quite clear from the question title, do you want to know where that folder came from? Maybe you have running workflows, information management policies, timer jobs that create-update files. There are a lot of options here. Try analyzing file creation dates and ULS logs for same moments.

Comment: there is any timer jobs that update files in filestream rbs foder?